# Atomic assignment of long value in java

Tags: java, volatile, java.util.concurrent, atomic-long

I have the use case to update epoch time of events in a long variable. This variable will have lots of concurrent reads and writes as well. Here are the requirements in detail:

1. Very fast completion of reads and writes
2. Reads may or may not return latest result but should not return corrupted result
3. Writes are simple assignment to a new epoch value, no addition, subtraction or calculation is required

Which of the alternatives is a better option for my use case:

1. primitive long with volatile keyword
2. AtomicLong
3. LongAccumulator with accumulatorFunction being `(x,y) -> y`
4. Two different variables - one for only reading values and other  a volatile variable just for writing value, the value of write variable one being copied to read variable in some interval

Comment: If you don't actually care about reading the right value, why do you care about storing the value at all?

Comment: The value is the current timestamp which is updated by 5000 threads concurrently(within a second), I only require it to be approximately accurate to 1 minute. Hence am tolerant to reads returning value about less than a minute older

Comment: 5K threads. I smell a serious design problem.

Comment: This is a spring boot server, the server can receive 5k http request per second. In each http request I need to update the variable. Agreed each http request might not translate to a new jvm thread

Comment: Probably an atomic long is more than good enough in your case. Probably some atomic read modify write behaviour is needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use `AtomicLong` as it helps to avoid additional overhead of explicit locking

Comment: Why is that better than `volatile`?

Comment: @VGR Using ```volatile``` what we can achieve is communication effects of ```synchronization```; not ```atomicity```. To perform atomic operation, we need to guard write access to ```volatile``` member with ```synchronization```.

On the other hand, you can use ```AtomicLong``` without an additional explicit guard with ```synchronization```

For better understanding, read ```Item 78``` from ```Effective Java - Joshua Bloch```